# Buffer overflow in Apache Ignite

Tags: c++, arm, ignite

We are running Apache Ignite on a ARM machine with 2GB of RAM. Whenever we try to `put` a large number of keys (in the hundreds) the process suddenly terminates with below error.

```
    *** buffer overflow detected 
    ***: /opt/XXX/XXXXx terminated
```

We are using the thick client and it is the server that crashes. The data directory goes into a corrupt state and needs to be cleared.

We are using the C++ client.

Are we missing some configuration or parameter. The same thing runs fine on AMD.

Some more information after debugging

- This issue does not occur when persistence is disabled
- The number of files open when this issue occurs is higher than the system limits

Comment: Thick client or thin client? What crashes, the client or the server? What's logged on the other side? Assume both client and server are on the same ARM machine?

Comment: Do you have big endian or little endian byte order?

Comment: @StephenDarlington The server crashes and goes into a invalid state i.e. we need to clean the file system to be able to use again. We are using the thick client

Comment: @isapego We are using little endian

Answer (score 0):

We have turned off the 32-bit thick client tests since it was crashing often due to insufficient resources. We advise using thin client in this case.

It's not just being low on memory but the total amount of available virtual address space is split between OS, C++ and Java, and it's just 4G.